# PDO bind array index (postgresql JSONB) for reading

Tags: php, json, postgresql, pdo

I'm storing an array of objects in a postgresql JSONB column, i'm tring to load a property of the nth's object but fails to bind it with PDO.

Test setup

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$Db = new PDO('...');


    $Db->exec('CREATE TABLE public.test (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, jb JSONB NOT NULL )');

    $insert = $Db->prepare('INSERT INTO public.test(jb) VALUES (?)');

    $insert->execute([json_encode([
                                     'q' => 'Qst1'
                                     , 'a' => [['txt' => 'Ans1', 'isCorrect' => true], ['txt' => 'Ans2', 'isCorrect' => false], ['txt' => 'Ans3', 'isCorrect' => false], ['txt' => 'Ans4', 'isCorrect' => false]]
                                 ], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)]);
```

If i read the whole array i can check

```
$allAnswers = $Db->prepare("select jb->'a' from public.test where id=?");
$allAnswers->execute([1]);
$result  = json_decode($allAnswers->fetchColumn(),true);
foreach ([0,1,2,3,17] as $answerId) {
    if (!array_key_exists($answerId,$result) ) {
        echo $answerId,':','NULL',"\n";
    }
    else {
        $r = $result[$answerId]['isCorrect'];
        echo $answerId,':',($r?'TRUE':'FALSE'),"\n";
    }
}
```

But if i need only the nths i don't know how to bind that (I'm not getting error only null values)

```
$answerIsCorrect = $Db->prepare("select jb->'a'->?->>'isCorrect' from public.test where id = ?");
foreach ([0,1,2,3,17] as $answerId) {
    $succ = $answerIsCorrect->execute([$answerId, 1]);
    if (true !== $succ) {
        die('Execute failed');
    }
    $result = $answerIsCorrect->fetchColumn();
    echo $answerId,':',is_null($result)?'NULL':('true'===$result?'TRUE':'FALSE'),"\n";
}
```

Current Output

`0:NULL
1:NULL
2:NULL
3:NULL
17:NULL`

Excepted output

`0:TRUE
1:FALSE
2:FALSE
3:FALSE
17:NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly i found it

```
$answerIsCorrect = $Db->prepare("select jsonb_extract_path(jb->'a',?)->>'isCorrect' from public.test where id = ?");
```

instead of

```
$answerIsCorrect = $Db->prepare("select jb->'a'->?->>'isCorrect' from public.test where id = ?");
```

worked